# python NameError: name 'ftax' is not defined

Tags: python, user-defined-functions, nameerror, function

I've been reading on your site for a couple of days and trying to debug my first python program that calculates the retail price + taxes and gives you the final price.

this is the error I get when I run it on python IDLE 3.4.2 on mac:

```
Enter the retail price $200
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sale tax.py", line 36, in <module>
    total = calc_total(retailprice, ptax, ftax)
NameError: name 'ftax' is not defined
```

As suggested in other posts, I try to define ftax as a global variable outside main() and then calling it in the function but it doesn't work.

Below is my code as per the error message without global variable:

```
def main():
    print ('The sale tax calculator program')
    print

def input_retail():
    retailprice = input('Enter the retail price $')
    retailprice = float(retailprice)
    return retailprice

def calc_ptax(retailprice):
    ptax= retailprice * 0.099
    return ptax

def calc_ftax(retailprice):
    ftax = retailprice * 0.05
    return ftax

def calc_total(retailprice,ptax,ftax):
    total = retailprice + ptax + ftax
    return total

retailprice = input_retail()
ptax = calc_ptax(retailprice)
tax = calc_ftax(retailprice)
total = calc_total(retailprice, ptax, ftax)

def print_info(retailprice,ptax,ftax,total):

    print( 'The retailprice is $' , retailprice)
    print ('The QST amount is $' , ptax)
    print ('The GST amount is $', ftax)
    print ('The total amount is $', total)

print_info(retailprice, ptax, ftax, total)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your program.

```
tax = calc_ftax(retailprice)
```

should be

```
ftax = calc_ftax(retailprice)
```

Comment: Wow, that was fast, can you tell I am still at the a, b, c's of learning to code with python? Hahaha, I feel stupid, I lost sleep over this, I guess I learned my lesson, I need to wear my astigmatism reading glasses more often and take breaks, I am impressed by this site, I should of subscribed a long time ago, hopefully some of my future questions will be more intelligent, cheers and feliz 2015 and thanks a lot.

Comment: @Jueves glad to help. If my answer solved your problem, feel free to [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the check mark. Also, I'd **highly** recommend reading through the rest of the [help] to get a feel for the site, what sorts of things are on- and off-topic, and generally discover what SO is all about. Thanks.

Comment: All good, you help me a lot, I am going to get familiar with the site so I don't ask until before I research better and inspect my code more carefully.

Comment: @Jueves glad to hear it, and welcome to SO!